# Android java application unable to handle interruptions

Tags: java, android

We are developing a unique android java app which sends pictures to friends to solve a puzzle (just like Instagram) while using the app when there is an interruption for e.g., a call, or when device goes to sleep , a new timer starts running along with the old timer simultaneously.
Can you guys suggest on how to resolve this bug ?

```
                    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(180000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                       // how.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + "seconds remaining: " );
                       if(countTime.equals("yes"))
                     {
                         how.setText(count+" ");
                           //how.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000  );
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         //how.setText(count+" Seconds");
                         how.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " seconds remaining" );
                     }
                     how.setTextSize(30);
                     count++;      
                     if(count==180)
                     {
                          T.cancel();
                         T=null;   


                           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                              MainActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                          }, 5000);

                     }
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        how.setText("Time Is Up!");
                    }
                 }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoints on when this piece of code is called and try to figure out when it is called. Make sure it is not called from your code more than once (as you want). If it does get more than once: where does this code reside? In the onResume, onPause, onCreate? Maybe the code should reside somewhere else or maybe use checks whether or not to enable a new timer ( if(!timerIsRunning){...} )?
Otherwise it might be a bug in Android and I'd suggest to use a different timer.